# Question about highlighted part of this short text

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The first official said the U.S. military is more confident right now about the Iraqi military's ability to protect Baghdad. The Iraqi brigades defending the capital are more capable and include U.S. military advisers,  **so at least Washington should have a better sense there if there's any imminent danger** .

1. I wonder if this is a guess ( must have, should have ) or a first conditional ? Could you please determine what grammar has been use here?
2. I wonder if you could help me, simplify the highlighted part in simple English?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it just looks like the first conditional but really states a guess: they should have a better sense of whether there's danger or not. Then *should* probably has the sense of "logical necessity" (as "must" has sometimes). Otherwise, it's hard to explain the *there* after *sense*.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions about the highlighted part:

1. Could you please determine what grammar has been used here?

   - You are correct with your first guess of it being a guess. In linguistics, this is called an [Epistemic Modality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality). It may have a lot of clutter around it and be using vague terms (ostensibly to avoid having to issue a later [retraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction)), but speaker is communicating a guess based on the state of affairs.
2. Could you simplify "...so at least Washington should have a better sense there if there's any imminent danger" in simple English?

   - The US Military (in Washington) should now have a better idea of how much danger exists in Baghdad, and when it will occur, thanks to the conditions described. The text goes on to imply that it might not *actually* be better, but that even in the worst-case scenario, it should not be any *worse*.

Answer (score 0):

The bold text is filled with "weasel words".  "Weasel words" are used to pretend to say something that seems strong -- but with loopholes, so the statement is really very weak.

In this example, "so at least Washington should have a better sense there if there's any imminent danger" seems to say something strong:  "The U.S. government will know what is going on.  The Iraqi government will be safe in Baghdad."

But look at the "weasel words":

- "at least":  The author is only saying something weak; the author is afraid to say something strong.  "at most" would have been a different "weasel phrase".  "at most" would mean that the author is not willing to say anything.
- "should have": As you noticed, the author does not say "does" or "will".  "Does" and "will" are straight-forward.  "Should have" allows for a bunch of ways that the following statement might not be true.
- "a better sense":  The author does not say "an understanding" or "a good sense".  "A better sense" just has to be better than something -- which might be a very poor sense.
- "if":  The author does not say there is no danger.  Instead, the author says there might be a danger.
- "imminent": The author is only talking about dangers that are about to happen now, or very soon.  The author does not talk about dangers that are inevitable, or likely in the medium-term, *et cetera*.
- Also notice that the quote does *not* say that the U.S. government will do anything useful, even if it does understand what is going on.

When you realize how much of the statement is weasel words, the statement does not say much at all.